# Getting Unncecessary whiteline space in the iCal attachment in Visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, visualforce-component, html, messaging-attachment

I have a visualforce email template which has a Ical/Calender notification attachment
,which body is handled in a visualforce component.
Afte downloading the iCal attachment and opening in a notepad i am getting a whitepace line above the body content.
Can anyone please suggest any steps to remove that white space line.
Thanks in Advance!
[image]

[image]

Example:
[image]

Comment: Please paste your code as text. This improves accessibility and also allows us to copy-paste your code to make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you added whitespace in the `messaging:attachment`. Try:

```
<messaging:attachment filename="EXA_Planned_Work.ics"
><c:EXA_PlannedCaseIcaVFTemp EmailComm="{!relatedTo}" ...
></messaging:attachment>
```

Notice how I move the > to the next line so that the following < is directly touching without whitespace. This should remove the blank line.